# Difference between Express and Standard Replacement Service for iPad battery

Tags: ipad, battery, repair

Can a user use Express Replacement Service to get a new battery if still under warranty?

How's that different than Battery Replacement Service again under warranty?

Comment: You had two questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your second question, but feel free to ask it separately.

Answer (score 1):

With express service you'll get a replacement device before sending back your old one. That way you don't have to spend time without a device. 
It's available under warranty but will be charged.

Price in Austria is 29€ incl. TAX to give you an idea.

Comment: Are you charged even while still in warranty/coverage in Australia?

Comment: *Austria ;) - only if you want the express service.

Comment: Sorry.  Misread.  Still, I thought that it was free, but a hold gets on your card.  Maybe I remember wrong then and there is a small fee plus the hold for the replacement device to send back the original device again.

Comment: When you have AppleCare express is free. That's how it's handled here anyways. Might be different in other countries.